# toString() produces Server error - Code execution mysteries

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function fc () {
 var x = 11
 var y = x.toString()
 return y
}
```

I execute this in a script file bound to a spreadsheet,
and get a the following error message:

*We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.*

If I execute that same function in another script file,
it works as expected, without error message.

The same happens with "simply" changing x to string:

```
var x = "11"
```

There may be an "easy" explanation but while you are at it, it feels
like living a Gary Larson-Cartoon ...

Comment: How long have you been trying? Typically the resolution for this is waiting 24 hours and trying again.

Comment: Can you share the other parts of the script. More likely the issue is not related to this function.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran that script with no problems.  I think I've had that error msg before for something that didn't have anything to do with the server.  It's impossible to capture every possible error perfectly.  Once in a while you get a misleading error.  I'm not saying that definitely is the situation, but just keep it in mind.

You have to go through the debugging process.  I've had to comment out large sections of code many times and go back to the beginning to trace errors.  Sometimes that's the only way.  Start commenting out code  until you get something to run without an error, then add lines back in until another failure.